# Is the fixed point property for posets preserved by products?

Tags: set-theory, open-problems, order-theory, posets, fixed-point-theorems

Recall that a partially ordered set (poset) $P$ has the fixed point property (FPP) if any order preserving function $f:P\longrightarrow P$ has a fixed point.

**Theorem.** Suppose $P$ and $Q$ are posets with the FPP and at least one of them is finite. Then $(P\times Q)$ has FPP.

Note: $(a,b)\le(c,d)$ if and only if  $a\le c$ and $b\le d$.

**Question.** Suppose $P$ and $Q$ are two infinite posets with the FPP. Does $(P\times Q)$ have the FPP ?

Comment: Are you just after nasty counterexamples, or are you also interested in how to make the FPP property well behaved? If the later, see "Complete axioms for categorical fixed point operators" by Alex Simpson and Gordon Plotkin (http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/als/Research/fixpoints.ps.gz) where they define suitable uniformity conditions for FPP property to behave well.

Answer (score 18):

This an open problem, as far as I know. The finite case was solved by [Roddy in 1994](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01462225).

There were some more general results proved by other people later:
see [this paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs40065-012-0049-7) by Bernd S. W. Schröder for a survey of history and recent results about FPP in posets.

Comment: (All the other references here are behind a paywall but) the Schroder paper contains some interesting arguments that are similar to ones that have been used in domain theory. Unfortunately, the discussion on this page is an example of the way that pure mathematicians and computer scientists (by which I mean the inhabitants of university buildings so called - we are all mathematicians) talk past one another. I have given a similar theorem and its background from computer science - what it the background for these fixed point results for posets in pure mathematics (departments)?

Comment: @PaulTaylor I am not sure what you are asking for, but perhaps you will be interested in another paper of Schroeder that is not behind a paywall: http://www.csi.uottawa.ca/ordal/papers/schroder/FINSURVE.html (I also recommend his book). A recent paper of Szymik (http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s11083-014-9332-x or in preprint version http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.6496) gives some insight into the "meaning" of the "strong fixed point property" described in your answer, my answer and Schroeder's paper.

Answer (score 12):

The question you asked is one of the main [long-open](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF00396277) problems in fixed point theory of posets.

Commenting on Paul Taylor's interesting answer: the property he describes is called *strong fixed point property* in order theory. In fact, if **one** of the posets $P,Q$ has the strong fixed point property and the other has usual fixed point property, then the product $P\times Q$ has the fixed point property. (If both of them have the strong fixed point property, then $P\times Q$ also has the strong fixed point property.) This was proved by [Duffus and Sauer in 1980](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF00337886). Fixed point property is not equivalent to strong fixed point property even for finite posets ([Pickering, Roddy 1992](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF00420349)).

Some approaches that are not mentioned in Schröder's survey mentioned by Gejza Jenča have been presented by Josef Niederle [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.2478/s12175-007-0025-4) and [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s11083-007-9072-2).

**EDIT** (made following one of Paul Taylor's comments)**:** Unfortunately all of the papers cited above are behind a paywall. However, one can find free conference versions of Niederle's  work: [here](http://math.muni.cz/~niederle/ftp/papers/fpp050425.ps) and [here](http://math.muni.cz/~niederle/ftp/papers/srf060516.pdf).

Answer (score 11):

Strengthening the hypotheses on $P$ and $Q$ from a fixed point *property* (every endofunction has *some* fixed point) to the existence of a fixed point *operator* $\mathsf{fix}$ with
$$ \text{for any } f:P\to P, \qquad f({\mathsf{fix}}(f)) = {\mathsf{fix}}(f), $$
there is a standard theorem in **domain theory** or **lambda calculus** (theoretical computer science) due to **Hans Bekić**.

We are given $h:P\times Q\to P\times Q$.  Define
$$ f = \lambda x.{\mathsf{fix}}_P(\lambda y.\pi_1(h(x,y))) : P\to Q $$
$$ g = \lambda y.{\mathsf{fix}}_Q(\lambda x.\pi_0(h(x,y))) : Q\to P $$
which have the properties that
$$ f x = \pi_1(h(x,f x))  \quad\text{and}\quad g y = \pi_0(h(g y,y)). $$
Now let $x_0 = {\mathsf{fix}}_P(\lambda x.g(f x))$ and $y_0=f(x_0)$, so $x_0=g(y_0)$.
Then
$$ \pi_0(h(x_0,y_0)) = \pi_0(h(g y_0,y_0)) = g(y_0) = x_0 $$
$$ \pi_1(h(x_0,y_0)) = \pi_1(h(x_0,f x_0)) = f(x_0) = y_0 $$
so $(x_0,y_0)$ is a fixed point of $h$.

In fact $f$ and $g$ are variables in this, so the argument provides a fixed point *operator* for $P\times Q$.

Hans Bekić was a member of the IBM Vienna Laboratory but died in a mountain accident in 1982, leaving a lot of his work unpublished.  It was edited and published by Cliff Jones and is available [here](http://homepages.cs.ncl.ac.uk/cliff.jones/publications/LNCS177-Bekic/). The result above is on pages 38-9 of Bekic2.pdf in this directory.

Google seems to think that this surname has an acute rather than a hachek.

Comment: A remark, since some, like me, might not find this immediately obvious given the context of the question, $\mathsf{fix}_P:P^P \to P$ is assumed to be a homomorphism in the contextual category, otherwise there is no reason to believe that $f$ and $g$ are homomorphisms. In the context of the question, this means that $\mathsf{fix}_P:P^P \to P$ must be order preserving, where $P^P$ has the pointwise ordering; it cannot merely select an arbitrary fixed point for each $f:P \to P$.

Comment: @Rahman.M: The bottom line for posets (as I tried to clarify above) is that if there are *order-preserving* fixpoint operators $\mathsf{fix}_P:P^P\to P$ and $\mathsf{fix}_Q:Q^Q\to Q$ then $P \times Q$ has the FPP. Here $P^P$ (similarly $Q^Q$) is the set of all order-preserving functions $P \to P$ with the pointwise ordering (i.e., $f \leq g \iff (\forall p \in P)(f(p) \leq g(p))$).

Comment: As`Andrej said, whether you regard this as an "open" problem depends on whether you're looking for a theorem or a counterexample.  In any area of mathematics, a random conjecture expressed in inappropriate generality is likely to be false, with unenlightening counterexamples. This result comes from the practical task of giving mathematical meaning to programming languages.  As Francois explains, it requires a cartesian closed category with fixed point operators; domain theory provided many such categories. Yes, I agree that the argument is bizarre.

Comment: In other words, mathematical questions often become simpler, when one makes simplifying assumptions.

Comment: The URL of the Jones link suggests that the same notes were finally published as http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2FBFb0048933 , is that right?

Comment: I believe Emil's reference is correct.  Maybe he can also tell us whether Bekic's name should have an acute or hachek.

Comment: There are many interesting professional issues behind Joel's comment that I would be delighted to debate with him.  Moreover, MathOverflow, as an interdisciplinary site, ought to be the place in which to do so.  Unfortunately, its oligarchy has succeeded in preventing any such debate from taking place.

Comment: Paul, your repeated gibes about 'oligarchy', 'Thought Police', etc. are extremely tiresome. I do encourage you to have a chat with Joel David Hamkins; you can use an SE chat room for that purpose. In fact, go right ahead and exchange some comments here; just try to keep in mind that StackExchange sites are, by design, not congenial to extended open-ended discussions.

Comment: @PaulTaylor: Sorry, I can’t tell. The name appears Bosnian in origin and as such would be written Bekić, but people in Central Europe—and within the Habsburg empire in particular—have moved and mingled a lot and acquired foreign names in the process, whose spelling may then change. This may well have happened here, as suggested by the distinctly German name Hans. It’s impossible to guess the proper spelling of his surname without looking up his family history, or better yet, his birth certificate.

Comment: I am happy to have a discussion here. The extra hypothesis amounts to a uniformity assumption that naturally makes the problem easier, but I don't actually have a good sense for which partial orders are ruled out by it. I can imagine partial orders with the FPP, where the particular fixed point depends on which way a certain part is moved, in such a way that an operator would be prevented. But I don't understand it well enough to see how far apart the question is from this way of answering. (Lastly, I don't know what you mean by "professional issues".)