# Fixed points and universal maps for posets

Tags: posets, fixed-point-theorems

In a recent post about [f.p.p. for poset products](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179790/is-fixed-point-property-for-posets-preserved-by-products), @M.Mirabi brought back an old-standing problem about the fixed point property of the product of two arbitrary posets which already enjoy the fixed point property. Thus it may be useful to shake up the topic by asking related questions.

The notion of a universal mapping applies to posets too. Thus in the context of posets, given two posets $\ X\ Y,\ $ and their order-preserving function $\ u : X\rightarrow Y,\ $ function $\ u\ $ is universal $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ $ for every order-preserving $\ f:X\rightarrow Y\ $ there exists $\ x\in X\ $ such that $\ f(x) = u(x)$.

We see that $\ X\ $ has the fixed point property $\ \Leftrightarrow\ $ identity $I_X:X\rightarrow X$ is universal. Also, if $\ u:X\rightarrow Y\ $ is universal then $\ Y\ $ has the fixed point property. More generally, if $\ v\circ u\ $ is universal then so is $\ v$.

**QUESTIONS:**

**Q1.**   Given universal order-preserving $\ f : X\rightarrow Y\ $ and $\ g : Y\rightarrow Z$, is the composition $\ g\circ f:X\rightarrow Z\ $ universal too?

**Q2.**   Given universal order-preserving $\ f : X\rightarrow Y\ $ and $\ f' : X'\rightarrow Y'$, is the cartesian product $\ f\times f':X\times X' \rightarrow Y\times Y'\ $ universal too?

REMARK: If the composition of a finite sequence of mappings is not universal then also their product is not universal.

> Problems about fixed point property for general objects can be sometimes (often) approximated by, and reduced to finite situations (like finite polyhedra in the topological case).

**TERMINOLOGY:**   The order in a cartesian product $\ X\times Y$ of two posets is meant in the sense of the categorical direct product, i.e.

$$(x\ y)\ \le\ (x'\ y')\quad\Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\quad (x\le x'\ \ \&\ \ y\le y')$$

Comment: Very nice & natural questions! Do you have an intuition as to Q1?

Comment: @dominiczypen, thank  you for kind words. I'd need to go back to my topic of the universal maps and universal morphisms. It's been half a century ago :-)

Comment: I was wondering, is there a universal property in "category theory language" that captures the essence of a universal map? - I guess, I better make this a real question (with a category-theory tag).

Comment: The full categorical definition is given in  Włodzimierz Holsztyński, *Universal Mappings and Fixed Points Theorems*, Bull Acad Polon Sci, v.XV, No 7, 1967, pp.433-438. Quote: DEFINITION. A morphism $\ f:Y\rightarrow X\ $ in category $\ K\ $ is *universal* if for any morphism $\ g: Y\rightarrow X\ $ there is in $\ K\ $ an object $\ Z\ $ and a morphism $\ h:Z\rightarrow Y\ $ such that $\ f\circ h = g\circ h.\ $ Object $\ X\ $ is *stable* (it has the property analogous to fixed-point property) if the identity $\ i_X:X\rightarrow X\ $ is a universal morphism. No need to ask a *real question* :-)

Comment: In the case of topological category one should consider the category of non-empty spaces. In the case of Banach algebras one should consider the notion of the *co-universal morphism*.

Comment: One of the most attractive places to feature the universal maps was the topology of manifolds; but I cannot recover my old results. The notion should be naturally used in the theory of differential equations (and for functional equations too).

Comment: A categorical theorem (published in the Austrian bulletin from a talk in Vienn, January 1969): a finite composition of morphisms is universal when their product is universal (granted that it both the product and the composition exist). It was published earlier (sloppily--see further on) in Fund Math for maps (but I already had it for categories--just laziness and impatience, justified by the circumstances though).

Comment: Very nice! If you have time, you can copy the definition above as an answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/189377/universal-maps-as-a-universal-property

Comment: Hang on - I have a problem with your definition. If we take it to the category of posets, isn't **every** order-preserving universal (in your categorical definition) if we can take $Z = \emptyset$? (There is exactly one order preserving map from $\emptyset$ to any poset).

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen -- I have always, from the very beginning, stressed the fact that we need to consider the full subcategory on the **non-empty** spaces, posets, etc. We have to exclude the initial objects.