# "Universal maps" as a universal property

Tags: ct.category-theory

In the question [Fixed points and universal maps for posets](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/180252/fixed-points-and-universal-maps-for-posets), we find the following definition: if $P, Q$ are partially ordered sets, an order-preserving map $u:P\to Q$ is said to be *universal* if for every order-preserving map $f:P\to Q$ there is $p\in P$ such that $f(p) = u(p)$.

This definition is not poset-specific; it makes sense in a lot of other categories such as $\mathbf{Top}$.

Can we decribe the essence of a universal map in the language of category theory? Is there a universal property that captures universal maps?

Comment: Hmm, so in the example, this just says that the equalizer of $u$ with any parallel arrow is non-empty (i.e. not initial). Not sure if that can be rephrased as some sort of universal property.

Comment: Generally a universal property defines an object up to isomorphism, so I think the answer to your second question is 'no'.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Not quite. It says that the equalizer $E$ of $u$ with any other arrow admits a map $1 \to E$ from the terminal object, which is very different from being non-initial.

Comment: @ToddTrimble I was thinking specifically in $\mathbf{Top}$.

Comment: I was about to ask if there were any interesting examples of such maps in $\mathbf{Top}$ when I realized that many fixed point theorems are simply statements that the identity is universal in this sense.

Comment: Thank you, @Dominic, for finding the notion of universal maps and morphisms interesting.

Comment: You may, @Dominic, add some additional tags (or not :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full categorical definition of universal morphism was given in Włodzimierz Holsztyński, Universal Mappings and Fixed Points Theorems, Bull Acad Polon Sci, v.XV, No 7, 1967, pp.433-438:

**DEFINITION.**   A morphism  $\ u: Y\rightarrow X\ $ in category  $\ K\ $  is *universal* $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ $ for any morphism  $\ f: Y\rightarrow X\ $  there is an object  $\ Z\ $ in $\ K\ $  and a morphism  $\ p:Z\rightarrow Y\ $  such that  $\ g\circ p=u\circ p.\ $  Object  X  is *stable* (or has the *fixed morphism property*; analogous to the fixed-point property) if the identity  $\ i_X:X\rightarrow X\ $  is a universal morphism.

In the topological case one considers the full category of the **non-empty** topological spaces.

> **COMMENTS**

- There are topological theorems but only one non-obvious general categorical theorem (from late 1960s): Let the finite categorical product $\ \prod_{k=1}^n f_n \ $ of morphisms $\ f:X_{k-1}\rightarrow X_K\ $ be well-defined and universal. Then $\ f_n\circ\ldots\circ f_1 : X_0\rightarrow X_n\ $ is universal too.  (This gives examples of universal maps of finite polyhedra which have non-universal product, already in dimension 2). *I have a feeling thought that I can generalize the main theorem of the paper mentioned above to address all categories.*
- Categories with exactly one object are virtually monoids. Thus in the case of monoids we can talk about universal elements rather than universal morphisms. When $\ 1\ $ is universal then we can say that the monoid itself has the fixed-morphism property. The whole theory here is peculiar since there is only one object. If $\ 1\ $ is not universal then no element is.
- Topic *universal maps* is a join generalization of the topological dimension theory and of the fixed-point property topic. Some theorems involve--in the same result--the dimension and the fixed point theory (without explicitly mentioning universal maps), and they apply the universal maps in their proof.